# HTTP request delayed in Chrome if dev tools not open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a [webpage](http://34.213.8.35/tree) in an app that uses some JavaScript to fetch data from an [API endpoint](http://34.213.8.35/api/tree).

In Safari and FireFox, I can request the page multiple times in a row and the data is fetched and displayed promptly. In Chrome, by contrast, the data is fetched and displayed promptly only if the dev tools are open or if my cache is clear (though I'm not disabling the cache in the dev tools).

If the dev tools are not open or Chrome has cached the page, reloading the page takes about 10 seconds to make the request and display the data.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this behavior? [Full app source](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lab-apps/let-them-speak/let-them-speak.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API request in question used [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) to make the request. I replaced the isomorphic-fetch code with an old school AJAX request and now the requests are triggering immediately as expected.

**Before**:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const fetchTreeData = () => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch(config.endpoint + 'tree')
      .then(response => response.json()
        .then(json => ({
          status: response.status,
          json
        })))
      .then(({ status, json }) => {
        if (status >= 400) dispatch(treeRequestFailed())
        else dispatch(receiveTreeData(json))
      }, err => { dispatch(treeRequestFailed(err)) })
  }
}
```

**After**:

```
export const fetchTreeData = () => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    get(config.endpoint + 'tree',
      (data) => dispatch(receiveTreeData(JSON.parse(data))),
      (e) => console.log(e))
  }
}

const get = (url, success, err, progress) => {
  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        if (success) success(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } else {
        if (err) err(xmlhttp);
      }
    };
  };
  xmlhttp.onprogress = (e) => {if (progress) progress(e)};
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
};
```